# Are there any known issues with Firebase when using the same document ID in 2 different collections?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 collections of group IDs and I want to use the same document ID for a group in each of them. Are there any known issues with Firebase that this might cause?

```
groups/{groupID1}/...
mainGroups/{groupID1}/...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no issues with Firestore when using the same document ID in two collection. While Firestore's built-in ID generators are statistically guaranteed to never generate the same ID, the system doesn't rely on them being globally unique.