# When Firebase generates the document ID, is it possible of duplicated IDs in different collections?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

Let's suppose I have two collections: `users` and `cars`. They're not related at all.

I'm using the auto-generated document ID when adding new documents in both collections.

Is there any chance of Firebase auto-generating the same document ID in different collections?

Like `users.ABCD` and `cars.ABCD`.

It is possible to create documents with the same ID in different collections, but I'd like to know if this situation can happen with the auto-generated IDs.

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76151518/1202416) that Firestore's built-in ID generators are statistically guaranteed to never generate the same ID. Is it valid across all collections?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ID generated by Firestore SDKs is statistically guaranteed to be unique, which is a fancy way of saying that it is so random that you're unlikely to ever generate the same value again. There is no check against the actual data on the server, and the collection plays no part in this guarantee.